# How to set multiple colors to a floating Edittext's hint?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-textinputlayout

Is there a way to set multiple colors to the edittext's hint when wrapped by android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout without compromising the behaviour of floating edittexts?

AFAIK The only way to set multiple colors to the edittext hint is by using SpannableStringBuilder. But when the editext is wrapped by TextInputLayout and the hint set programmatically using a SpannableStringBuilder, it behaves like a normal editext which does not float (the labels aren't floating)

Whereas if the hint is set through the xml it works as a floating edittext but in this case the hint would be single colored

I am looking for a way to add multiple colors to the edittext while the floating labels work intact.

Comment: you want the text to be differently colored or hint to be differently colored?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan :  I think OP wants hint to be differently colored.

Comment: wonder if there is a way to change the textinputlayout hint color dynamically. ?

Comment: @Mistaken you cannot change the hint color of Text Input Layout dynamically.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan : Did you figure out why it can't be done? I was trying to set this using html string, but couldn't do it. What's the reason fir that?

Comment: By default Hint color of textinput layout was in color of the colorAccent by default. If you want use different color you need to customize different styles

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan the color of the hint does change as per the spannable but for some reason programmatically setting hint prevents the floating behaviour of TextInputLayout. I guess the sethint() overrides some of the TextInputLayout methods