# Setting TextInputLayout hint using html string

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout

As a follow up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551570/how-to-set-multiple-colors-to-a-floating-edittexts-hint), I was trying to pass a html string to `setHint()` method of `TextInputLayout`. But it's not working.

Using that html string input to `setText()` method of a `TextView` is obviously working.
Going into the implementation of this method, in the parent method which is called at the end of `setText()` call (you can view the function [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/TextView.java#3922)), I was trying to figure out what extra is being done here to handle that html string that can't be done in case of setting `TextInputLayout` hint. Maybe it's related to the `BufferType` argument that's passed here. Maybe not. I couldn't figure it out actually.

As we know, same parent method is called when you call `setText()` on an `EditText`.

Going into the detail of `setHint()` method of `TextInputLayout`, I was thinking that maybe it also uses an internal textview and using that, maybe we can somehow achieve it.
I saw that it uses an instance of the class `CollapsingTextHelper`. After looking into it for a while, I didn't go beyond it.

So, my question is, can we achieve it?  Can we set an html string to behave properly when it is set as a hint to the `TextInputLayout`.

Example html string : `CharSequence text = "<font color='#cc0029'>write any thing here</font> <font color='#ffcc00'>write any thing here 2</font>";`.

So for this, hint should be displayed in appropriate colors as mentioned.

Comment: any luck ........?

Comment: umm, it was long back. But as far as I remember, I couldn't do it. Let me know if you are able to achieve it somehow.